# access gui from other methode

Tags: java, class, user-interface

i want to write a program which automatically calls an admin when something happens in a database. The number which to call should be entered in a `TextField` and after pressing a button it should be written in a variable.

So my gui class looks like this:

```
package ui_test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class UI implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JButton button;
JTextField textField;
JTextField textFieldInfo;
private String adminTelNumber = "";

public UI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Caller GUI");
    panel = new JPanel();
    textField = new JTextField();
    textFieldInfo = new JTextField();
    textField.setText("Nummer eingeben!");
    textFieldInfo.setText("Hier kommt die Info!");
    button = new JButton("Übernehmen");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(textFieldInfo);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button){
        adminTelNumber = textField.getText();
        textFieldInfo.setText(this.getAdminTelNumber().toString().trim());
    }   
}

public String getAdminTelNumber() {
    return adminTelNumber;
}
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
package ui_test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class UiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UI ui = new UI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        doSomething();
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        String telNumber = ui.getAdminTelNumber();
    }
}
```

How can i call `getAdminTelNumber` or access the `adminTelNumber` variable like i wanted in `doSomething`?

By the way...the real `doSomething` has an endless while loop with sleep timer inside it. Every repetition it should check if the `adminTelNumber` got changed. So it should call the actual number.

Hope you can help me...im very noob :D

Thanks!

Comment: You could add UI as a parameter to your doSomething Method or create an instance variable inside your UiTest Class, that you can use in your doSomething method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems you have to solve here:

Firstly, accessing the UI from the other thread at all. This is the easy part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                final UI ui = new UI();
                new Thread() {
                  public void run() {
                    doSomething(ui);
                  }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public static void doSomething(UI ui) {
```

Secondly, accessing the UI from the other thread *in a thread-safe way* - the easiest way is to just make the reads and the writes synchronized:

```
public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

and

```
public synchronized String getAdminTelNumber() {
```

It would be more efficient to use `wait` and `notify` to notify when something has changed, but I think this may work OK as it is.

Comment: thanks a lot! i thought the ui has to be inside an own thread! but everything is fine now :)